# Mysql - Get records meet criteria in where clause

Tags: mysql

Please everyone helps me to write a query for this case. Thanks.

Table data

```
id  emp date  n1  n2  check 
-----------------------------
1   1   Mon   2   1   1     
2   1   Sun   1   0   0   
3   1   Sat   1   0   0
4   1   Fri   1   0   0
5   2   Mon   2   1   0
6   2   Sun   1   0   0  
7   2   Sat   1   0   0
8   2   Fri   1   0   0
```

Requirement:
Get records which having `date` is `Mon` and `n2` is 1 and `check` is 1. If having records, then also show records of same employee having `date` is (`Sun` or `Sat`) and `n1` is 1.

Then output should be:

```
id  emp date  n1  n2  check 
-----------------------------
1   1   Mon   2   1   1     
2   1   Sun   1   0   0   
3   1   Sat   1   0   0
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use nested queries.. Get the list of IDs of employees before getting the individual rows.

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename`
WHERE `emp` IN (
    SELECT `emp` FROM `tablename`
    WHERE `date` = "Mon" AND `n2` = 1 AND `check` = 1 GROUP BY emp
) AND (
    (`date` = "Mon") OR 
    (`date` IN ("Sat", "Sun") AND `n1` = 1)
)
```

Alternatively, you can run two queries separately, to simplify the logic regarding the `Mon/Sat/Sun` and `n1` part, and merge the two resultant arrays on your own.

Comment: Hi Irvin, this is not working. I need to have all records like above output. But your query is getting only `n1` = 1. Then, it's missing record id 1 which having `n1` = 2

Comment: An issue is if I have table with a huge rows, then the query runs very slow, because of the nested query. How do I should do to improve that?

Comment: Do you index your table by `emp`? You could try that.

Comment: Yes, I did. But it's still slow. Anyway, I can break to two queries and merge them. I feel it is faster :-|

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a FULL OUTER JOIN on the same table.

```
SELECT * FROM Table FULL OUTER Join Table WHERE Table.date = 'Mon' Or Table.n1 = 1;
```